# Efficient python string replace in 31GB file

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, large-files

I need to regularly large XML files which contain no line breaks and often contain XML syntactical problems. These files are huge, minimum 10GB.

My preferred solution would be to convert these files into one record per line to facilitate processing (i.e. whenever a record close tag is encountered, add a newline). Reading in chunks is one way of doing this, but it also strikes me as very awkward

Splitting it into multiple files that I could use normal methods on would be acceptable.

EDIT: example of syntactically correct record included below, but there are different types. Errors typically include encoding issues or invalid characters. Input files would contain millions of records in a single line. Desired output would be a file containing millions of lines, each with a single record.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><collection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"><record><leader>01052nam a2200301 i 4500</leader><controlfield tag="001">in1</controlfield><controlfield tag="005">20140804085243.0</controlfield><controlfield tag="008">760811s1975    enka     b    000 0 eng  </controlfield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="010"><subfield code="a">76364258</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="020"><subfield code="a">0900492856 :</subfield><subfield code="c">£0.50</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="035"><subfield code="a">(OCoLC)02966998</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="040"><subfield code="a">DLC</subfield><subfield code="c">DLC</subfield><subfield code="d">MTH</subfield><subfield code="d">m.c</subfield><subfield code="d">UtOrBLW</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1="0" ind2="0" tag="050"><subfield code="a">U162</subfield><subfield code="b">.A3 no.116</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="100"><subfield code="a">Rosecrance, Richard N.</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1="1" ind2="0" tag="245"><subfield code="a">Strategic deterrence reconsidered /</subfield><subfield code="c">by Richard Rosecrance.</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2="1" tag="264"><subfield code="a">London :</subfield><subfield code="b">International Institute for Strategic Studies,</subfield><subfield code="c">1975.</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="300"><subfield code="a">3 unnumbered pages, 37 pages :</subfield><subfield code="b">illustrations ;</subfield><subfield code="c">25 cm.</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="336"><subfield code="a">text</subfield><subfield code="b">txt</subfield><subfield code="2">rdacontent</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="337"><subfield code="a">unmediated</subfield><subfield code="b">n</subfield><subfield code="2">rdamedia</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="338"><subfield code="a">volume</subfield><subfield code="b">nc</subfield><subfield code="2">rdacarrier</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="490"><subfield code="a">Adelphi papers ;</subfield><subfield code="v">no. 116,</subfield><subfield code="x">0567-932X</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="500"><subfield code="a">Cover title.</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="504"><subfield code="a">Includes bibliographical references.</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650"><subfield code="a">Deterrence (Strategy)</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650"><subfield code="a">World politics</subfield><subfield code="y">1945-1989.</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650"><subfield code="a">World politics</subfield><subfield code="y">1989-</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1="2" ind2=" " tag="710"><subfield code="a">International Institute for Strategic Studies.</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="830"><subfield code="a">Adelphi papers</subfield><subfield code="v">no. 116.</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1="f" ind2="f" tag="952"><subfield code="d">AC Frost Stacks - AFRST</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="998"><subfield code="a">AM</subfield><subfield code="b">000000123</subfield></datafield><datafield ind1="f" ind2="f" tag="999"><subfield code="i">5f1d0f2a-0297-444c-88e1-ef7ae9795107</subfield><subfield code="s">eaa917fe-9c6f-4e14-b87f-3dd72cab1384</subfield></datafield></record>
```

What would be an efficient method for doing this?

Comment: We could benefit from having a snippet of the current format vs the desired one.

Comment: I'd fix the problem at the source. Who or what generates these XML files with syntactical problems?

Comment: Examples of these syntactical problems would also help us make suggestions.

Comment: The formats vary because there are different types of records, and syntactical problems typically involve invalid characters or encoding issues.

The reason I mentioned that is the obvious way to deal with a massive XML file is with SAX. But that's going to cause loads of headaches.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel These come from different sources at clients who either don't understand or control their own systems so fixing must be done at our end

Comment: "invalid characters or encoding issues" -- well, good luck to you then.

Comment: That's why I asked the question. I know messy ways to fix the problem. Thought I'd ask here because someone might know a good way. In bash, I'd just use sed for this, but I need to build GUI-based tools to help others.